# "Read more" image moving in column over text when resizing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hy!

This is my first question here and i'm posting it just because i have no ideea what i should do with my webpage to continue buiding it.

First, i'm sorry for my english, i know is bad.

Well, the problem is simple. I created 2 webpages, this being the second one. I deleted the first page because of the same problem, thinking i did something wrong, but here i have the same problem

After creating a simple menu and a "submenu", i wanted to create bellow a section with "Last articles", and i wanted to create 3 columns, with one image in every column, some text, and a "readmore" button.

All was great, but the "Read More" button isn't working as i want to, because when i resize the browser it's going over the text.

I had the same problem at the submenu but i fixed it, i have no ideea how, but i did it.

Now, can you tell me what i did wrong?

Here you have the page on JsBin http://jsbin.com/loxaxepoqe/1/edit?html,css,output .

It's not a profesional website, it's not even made to be used, it's just something i do for practice since I want to become a Web Designer, but if i can't build something as simple as this, i'll not be able to build something big.

Thank you for reading this and i hope you can help me!

Comment: `absolute` position ignores other elements on the page, which can cause overlapping. Try using relative positions instead.

Comment: @BrianBennett Thank you for the answere, i already tried relative position, but nothing, i put positon:relative on the center, on the text, on the "readmore" image, but nothing worked

Comment: @BrianBennett It worked -_-" I didn't used relative positioning where i sould have use it, now it's working, thank you!